# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'switch_to_alert'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making a simple crawler that can open a site and when a pop up appears, it should close it. but the following command isn't working.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.bnbaccessories.com/"
browser.get(url)

alert = webdriver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
browser.implicitly_wait(50)
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   alert = browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
```

instead

```
webdriver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
```

`driver` instance name is `browser` not `webdriver`

Comment: When I use browser.switch_to_alert().dismiss()  it gives a marked line on the switch to alert and asks to use the driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss() and the code still doesn't work.

Comment: @ I have updated answer. I have deleted the comment where I have explained. Please try and let me know. Make sure it is alert. Try to inspact **Yes and No** button on alert. if you can't inspect that means it is alert.